# how to create a dynamic url in gradle?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my project's build.gradle file. I am trying to create maven url dynamically. When I provide the commented hardcoded string, it works fine but when I give the uncommented dynamic string, it messes up.

foo.class is a string too. I have no idea what is wrong in this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def foo = System.getenv().get("ANDROID_HOME")
//def foo = "/Users/someone/Library/Android/sdk"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "$foo/extras/android/m2repository" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what happens when you run your build? What do you mean "it messes up?"

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case (Android support library dependency in java module) you can use snippet like this:

```
def logger = new com.android.build.gradle.internal.LoggerWrapper(project.logger)
def sdkHandler = new com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler(project, logger)
for (File file : sdkHandler.sdkLoader.repositories) {
    repositories.maven {
        url = file.toURI()
    }
}
```

You have to add Android Gradle plugin to classpath dependency (but don't apply it):
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

Reference: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife-compiler/build.gradle